# Cannot debug in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I restored my iPad using 4.3.1 and I use Xcode 3 , after upgrading I cannot debug it always raise warning and display black screen on iPad

> unable to load symbol file: warning: UUID mismatch detected with the loaded library - on disk is: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.1 (8G4)/Symbols/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib

best regards

Answer (score -1):

The edition does not match, this happened to me once also, nothing wrong with code or anything, just the 2 edition does not pair, you need to change one of them.